# How multiple requests happens from a web browser for a simple URL?

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, webserver

While trying to serve a page from node.js app I hit with this question. how multiple files are serving from a server with a simple request from user?

For eg:

1. A user enters www.google.co.in in address bar
2. *browser make a request to that url and it should end there with a response.* But whats happening is, few more requests are sending from that page to server like a chain.

What I am thinking now is, how my web browser(chrome) is sending those extra requests... Or who is prompting chrome to do it? and ofcourse, how can I do the same for my node.js app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once chrome gets the html back from the website, it will try to get all resources (images, javascript files, stylesheets) mentioned on the page, as well as favicon.ico That's what I think you are seeing

Answer (score 0):

You can have as many requests as you want, from the client side (browser), using [ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29). Here's a basic example using [jQuery.get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/), an abstraction of an ajax call:

```
$.get(
    "http://site.com",
    function(data) { alert(data); }
);
```